# How can i merge these 2 dataframes into one whilst matching data to rows?

Tags: r, merge, rbind

I have 2 dataframes which i need to make into one. The first is 'GDP' and the second is 'Death_rates'. I want to combine the data from both matching up to the country and year columns. Assume i need to use rbind but not sure on how to match up the data from the 2nd dataset with the first.

GDP has colnames of 'Country' 'Year' 'GDP'
Death_rates has colnames of 'Country' 'Year' 'Total deaths' 'Indoor deaths'
'Particlate matter' 'Ozone'

Intending to get one dataframe with 'Country' 'Year' 'Total deaths' 'Indoor deaths'
'Particlate matter' 'Ozone' 'GDP'

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  I suspect tidyverse's `*_join` family will help.

Comment: +1 please share your data to get help. But this sounds like a clear case requiring either `base::merge()` or `dplyr::*_join()`. `rbind()` is probably *not* what you want here.

Comment: Thanks, whats the easiest way to share the data on here?

Comment: You can share your data using `dput(data)` in an R session. You can choose a sample of your data, e.g., `dput(head(data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column names are `Country` and `Year` in both data frames, you can use

```
merge(data1, data2, by=c("Country", "Year"))
```

If they are different, use `by.x` and `by.y`.

Comment: Thanks, when I try this i get this error message; Merge(gdp, death_rates, by=c("Country", "Year"))
Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: Then try `by.x=c("colname.country.x","colname.year.x"), by.y=c("colname.country.y","colname.year.y")`, with the correct colnames, of course. You can find out the colnames with `names(gpd)` and `names(death_rates)`.

Comment: Still not having any luck... > merge(gdp, death_rates, by.x=c("colname.Country.x","colname.Year.x"), by.y=c("colname.Country.y","colname.Year.y"))
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns

Comment: Please replace "colname.country.x" etc with the actual column name. First find out the column names with `names(gdp)` and `names(death_rates)`, and then use THESE column names for merging.

Comment: ahh apologies, yeh thats worked now, thanks

Comment: Glad to hear this. Don't forget to accept the answer so that the thread is marked as answered.